# Is there a DBMS optimized for tree data structures?

Tags: database, nosql

I've searched the internet for quite some time now but to no avail. I'm looking for an Database to easily store and retrieve tree structures and possibly graphs. Not out of pressing need, but rather that I've implemented such structures several times now and wonder if I really have to do this over and over again....

Ideally, such an DBMS would support Statements like: (PSEUDO SQL)

```
CREATE TREE tree1;

INSERT NODE n1 INTO tree1.ROOT VALUES ('a', 'c')
INSERT NODE n2 INTO tree1.n1 VALUES ('b', 'c')
SELECT CHILDREN FROM tree1 WHERE n1 IS PARENT
SELECT PARENTS FROM tree1 WHERE n2 IS CHILD
```

I think it's clear what this is intended to mean. NODEs may have any data structure...

I know there are several ways to replicate tree or graph-structures in relational databases, but how come there is no specialized Database-System for such common data structures? Or did i miss it?

I've found so far [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org), which is looks quite interesting, but seems to have no specialized tree syntax. Document-oriented databases, on the other hand, store data hierarchical, but operations like getting children or parents are not easy to implement.

The closest to what i have in mind is Javascript/jQuery DOM-manipulation. You can navigate by path, query classes, ids and attributes, easily get/create children and parents.... but it's not a database system.

Do you have any recommendation, what database system is best suited for tree structures? So far I've only worked on relational databases.

Comment: for small trees (where you can afford to resubmit the whole tree on update) document databases should work fine, otherwise - yeah, perhaps graph DB

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out XML-databases? These can be queried using X-path expressions.

But most tree-datastructures in databases, that I have seen use a lot of client side
processing. So instead of formulating complex queries, 
you rather query the database using recursive functions, that walk the tree.
This might be unusual if you have a SQL background, but it is quite efficient.

This can be done with any NoSQL database, but neo4J makes it particularly easy.